# Timer based interrupt in PIC microcontroller using mikroC for PIC

Tags: c, pic, c89, mikroc

I am facing a problem while implementing a timer based interrupt in mikroC for PIC.

I want to toggle a port pin for 8 times if there is a keypress at PORTC.F0 and there should be a delay of say 100ms between the toggles.

Normally this would be very easy using a delay function

```
for (i=0;i<=8;i++)
 {
  PORTB.F0=~PORTB.F0;
  Delay_ms(100);
 }
```

But during the period, any other keypresses are missed by the system. So I thought of implementing the solution using interrupts.

```
#define SW PORTC.F0

char ttime,i;
volatile flag;

void Inittimer()
{
 T1CON         = 0x01;
 TMR1IF_bit    = 0;
 TMR1H         = 0x06;
 TMR1L         = 0x00;
 TMR1IE_bit    = 1;
 INTCON        = 0xC0;
}

void Interrupt()
{
 if (TMR1IF_bit)
 {
  TMR1IF_bit    = 0;
  TMR1H         = 0x06;
  TMR1L         = 0x00;
  ttime--;
  if (ttime==0)
  {
   flag=1;
  }
 }
}

void main()
{
 Inittimer1();
 TRISB    = 0;
 TRISC.F0 = 1;
 PORTB    = 0x00;
 while(1)
 {
 if (SW==0)
 {
  ttime=3;
 }
  if (flag==1)
  {
   for (i=0;i<=8;i++)
   {
    PORTB=~PORTB;
    flag=0;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Nothing is working. Can somebody please help me to correct the code?

Comment: "Nothing is working" is not a problem description. _What_ isn't working?

Comment: In hindsight, Nothing is working is indeed a very vague comment. I am trying to implement a PORT toggle every 100ms for exactly 8 times using timer interrupt. I tried working many options, none of them worked for me. The closest I came was to get the PORT toggled after a certain time delay using interrupt. But cannot stop it from toggling after n number of times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you initialize your timer:

```
void Inittimer()
{
 T1CON         = 0x01;
 TMR1IF_bit    = 0;
 TMR1H         = 0x06;  // No prescaler? I doubt your clock speed is 40-some KHz!
 TMR1L         = 0x00;
 TMR1IE_bit    = 1;
 INTCON        = 0xC0;
}
```

Why don't you control the LED directly from the ISR ?

```
  if (ttime)
      PORTB.F0 = (--ttime & 1);  // ttime is not decremented when led is not blinking.
  else
      PORTB.F0 = 0;              // ensures the LED is off.
```

To start blinking 8 times:

```
if (SW==0)
{
  PORTB.F0 = 1;
  ttime = 16;
}
```

Note that with a 100ms clock interrupt, the first 'blink' of the LED may last up to 200ms...  This is why many like to work with a faster timer interrupt (this has usually other uses as well), controlling the led would require adding a soft post-scaler

```
   if (blinking)
   {
      if (--blinkTimer == 0)
      {
         blinkTimer = BLINK_DELAY;      // whatever number it takes for 100ms.
         PORTB.F0 = (--blinking & 1);  
      }
   }
   else
   {
       PORTB.F0 = 0
   }
```

To start blinking:

```
if (SW==0)
{
  blinking = (2 * BLINKS) - 1;
  blinkTimer = BLINK_DELAY;
  PORTB.F0 = 1;
}
```

This should get you a more even first blink.

Comment: Thanks for the help Michael. I did solve the problem, can you please check if the approach is correct? `while(i<8) { if (flag==1){ i++; PORTB.F0 = ~PORTB.F0; cnt=0;flag=0; } }` This does toggle the port pin 8 times and setting the value of cnt allows be to precisely set thedelay with which the port pin is toggled. Is this approach correct?

Comment: It is correct, but it blocks your main loop.  What of all the other operations you may need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Well this doesn't look right:

```
  if (flag==1)
  {
   for (i=0;i<=8;i++)
   {
    PORTB=~PORTB;
    flag=0;
   }
  }
```

When you first see that `flag` is set, you immediately loop and toggle the output 8 times, *without* waiting for `flag` to turn back to 1. That's not right, it's overly simplified.

You need to look for the `flag`, then toggle the output and clear the `flag`, and wait for it to to get set again, maintaining the counter in parallel. The `for` loop is not the proper structure for this, since it will "lock out" the rest of the program and might cause keypresses to be missed.

Comment: I did try doing what you suggested...instead of the for loop, I incremented another variable i after the port was toggled and the flag was cleared. I did put a conditional statement of `if (i>=8) {PORTB=0x00; i=0;}`This did not work. Basically, I can start the PORT to toggle after certain delay but cannot understand how to stop it from toggling after n number of cycles.